# The teacher is always wrong, flip his answer

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

Your dumb teacher is always wrong, so flip his answer.

#### Change these responses

```
True -> False
Yes -> No 
0 -> 1
Yeah -> Nope
```

and vice versa. Keeping punctuation and the first letter's capitalization counts. Only one condition will be passed to the program.

**You only need to accept the following test cases**:

```
True <-> False
True. <-> False.
true <-> false
true. <-> false.
Yes <-> No
Yes. <-> No.
yes <-> no
yes. <-> no.
0 <-> 1  
Yeah <-> Nope
yeah <-> nope
Yeah. <-> Nope.
yeah. <-> nope.
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>45</s> <s>41</s> <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

#### Code:

```
“‰¦žä¥æ€¸pe…Ü€¸“ð¡2ôDí«D€™«vy`:D_D¹Êiq
```

#### Explanation:

It first starts with the compression:

```
“‰¦žä¥æ€¸pe…Ü€¸“
```

This is a compressed version of `"true false yeah nope yes no"`. After that, we split on the spaces with `ð¡`, resulting into:

```
['true', 'false', 'yeah', 'nope', 'yes', 'no']
```

We slice this array into pieces of 2 with `2ô`, resulting into:

```
[['true', 'false'], ['yeah', 'nope'], ['yes', 'no']]
```

We duplicate this array and reverse each element of it with `Dí`. Then we append this to our first array with `«`, resulting into:

```
[['true', 'false'], ['yeah', 'nope'], ['yes', 'no'], ['false', 'true'], ['nope', 'yeah'], ['no', 'yes']]
```

To get the titlecased words, we duplicate the array again and convert each word to titlecase with `€™`. Finally, this is appended to the initial array. So, the final list is:

```
[['true', 'false'],
 ['yeah', 'nope'],
 ['yes', 'no'],
 ['false', 'true'],
 ['nope', 'yeah'],
 ['no', 'yes'],
 ['True', 'False'],
 ['Yeah', 'Nope'],
 ['Yes', 'No'],
 ['False', 'True'],
 ['Nope', 'Yeah'],
 ['No', 'Yes']]
```

The imporant part here is that `Nope` comes *before* `No`. Eventually, we get to this part of the code:

```
vy`:D_D¹Êiq
```

Explanation:

```
v            # For each in the array...
 y`          #   Push the array (containing 2 words) and flatten.
   :         #   Replace the first word with the second.
    D_       #   Duplicate and negate (resulting 0 into 1 and 1 into 0).
                 If this is not possible, this results into nothing.
      D      #   Duplicate the top of the stack again.
       ¹Ê    #   If it's not equal to the inital input string...
         iq  #     Quit the program and implicitly print the processed string.
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCc4oCwwqbFvsOkwqXDpuKCrMK4cGXigKbDnOKCrMK44oCcw7DCoTLDtETDrcKrROKCrOKEosKrdnlgOkRfRMK5w4ppcQ&input=WWVzLg).

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 44 bytes

```
j\.XXXcz\.`M2)Jc."<unprintables>"\b)rR3J
```

Hexdump:

```
00: 6A5C 2E58 5858 637A 5C2E 604D 3229 4A63
10: 2E22 6179 0862 3C40 D23B 9A54 C2B4 A20A
20: FEE7 8701 225C 6229 7252 334A
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%5C.XXXcz%5C.%60M2%29Jc.%22ay%08b%3C%40%C3%92%3B%C2%9AT%C3%82%C2%B4%C2%A2%0A%C3%BE%C3%A7%C2%87%01%22%5Cb%29rR3J&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=True%0AFalse%0ATrue.%0AFalse.%0AYes%0ANo%0AYes.%0ANo.%0Ayes%0Ano%0Ayes.%0Ano.%0A0%0A1%0AYeah%0ANope%0Ayeah%0Anope%0AYeah.%0ANope.%0Ayeah.%0Anope.&debug=0)

Comment: updated question.

Comment: What are "<unprintables>"?

Comment: See hexdump or test-suite.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 217 bytes

Longer than I thought it would be...

```
Input Str1
If Str1="0
Then
Disp 1
Stop
End
"e"=sub(Str1,2,1
sub("FalsefalseNopenope",1+5not(Ans)(sub(Str1,1,1)="t")+10Ans+4Ans(sub(Str1,1,1)="y"),5-Ans-2(sub(Str1,3,1)="s"))+sub(" .",1+(sub(Str1,length(Str1),1)="."),1
```

Comment: Can’t you save a byte by using ‘Return’ instead of ‘Stop’, since Return is a 1-byte token?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Good question. "Return" could be used instead of "Stop" here; since there are no subprograms, the behavior would be identical. However, Stop is also a 1-byte token (0xD9), so there is no compelling reason to use one over the other.

Comment: Hmm. My brain was for some reason telling me that Stop was 2 bytes. I must have been thinking of something else. Sorry!

Comment: @HelloGoodbye No problem! Here's a useful page (which you may already know about) that I refer to frequently to check if tokens are 1 byte: http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens

Comment: Yep, that’s the one I use!

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 227 bytes

```python
def f(x):l=["True","False","True.","False.","true","false","true.","false.","Yes","No","yes","no","Yes.","No.","yes.","no.","0","1","Yeah","Nope","Yeah.","Nope.","yeah","nope","yeah.","nope."];r=l.index(x);return l[r+1-2*(r%2)]
```

Ungolfed form:

```python
def f(x):
    l=["True","False","True.","False.","true","false","true.","false.","Yes","No","yes","no","Yes.","No.","yes.","no.","0","1","Yeah","Nope","Yeah.","Nope.","yeah","nope","yeah.","nope."]
    r=l.index(x)
    return l[r + 1 -2*(r % 2)]
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, <s>51</s> 44 bytes

```
.d̾ॗǣ/ற㻯dc2cDMl4+D.F\.+)+T`]1+Dm_+Y@
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.d%06%CC%BE%E0%A5%97%C7%A3%2F%E0%AE%B1%E3%BB%AFdc2cDMl4%2BD.F%5C.%2B%29%2BT%60%5D1%2BDm_%2BY%40&input=%22yes%22)

```
.d̾ॗǣ/ற㻯dc2c                         - {'yeah': 'nope', 'true': 'false', 'yes': 'no'}
             DMl4+                    - ^ += map(^, str.title())
                  D.F\.+)+            - ^ += map(^+".")
                          T`]1+       - ^ += [repr(10)]
                               Dm_+   - ^ += map(^, reversed)
                                   Y@ - dict(^)[input]
```

Comment: Hexdump: `2E64 CCBE E0A5 97C7 A32F E0AE B1E3 BBAF 6463 3263 444D 6C34 2B44 2E46 5C2E 2B29 2B54 605D 312B 446D 5F2B 5940`

Comment: It is actually 44 bytes, unless there's a null byte somewhere.

Comment: @LeakyNun I'm still getting 45 bytes... It doesn't have a null byte in it

Comment: Mind putting down your hexdump?

Comment: `2e 64 06 CC BE E0 A5 97 C7 A3 2F E0 AE B1 E3 BB AF 64 63 32 63 44 4d 6c 34 2B 44 2e 46 5C 2E 2B 29 2B T 60 5D 31 2B 44 6d 5f 2B 59 40` - Ok, 44 then

Comment: Well, there's a `06` in the third byte in your hexdump.

Comment: Hexdump: `2E64 06CC BEE0 A597 C7A3 2FE0 AEB1 E3BB AF64 6332 6344 4D6C 342B 442E 465C 2E2B 292B 5460 5D31 2B44 6D5F 2B59 40` (45 bytes)

Comment: That was by looking at the URL in the try-it link

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>86</s>  81 bytes

```perl6
{my@a=<true yes yeah 1 0 nope no false>;my%h=@a Z=> reverse @a;S:ii/(@a)/{%h{lc $0}}/}
{my@a=<true yes yeah 1 0 nope no false>;S:ii/(@a)/{%(@a Z=> reverse @a){lc $0}}/}
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{
  # list of responses ordered in such a way that
  # reversing it will give you the opposite response
  my @a = <true yes yeah 1 0 nope no false>;

  # create a lookup table
  my %h = @a Z=> reverse @a;

  # the :samecase / :ii modifier causes the regex to call .samecase
  # on the replacement, and also turns on :ignorecase / :i
  S:samecase /
    (@a) # match against the values in @a
  /{
    %h{lc $0}
  }/
}
```

#### Test:

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;
use Test;

my @tests = (
  < True False >, < True. False. >, < true false >, < true. false. >,
  < Yes  No >, < Yes. No. >, < yes  no >, < yes. no. >,
  < 0 1 >,
  < Yeah Nope >, < yeah nope >, < Yeah. Nope. >, < yeah. nope. >,
);

plan @tests * 2;

my &answer-flip = {my@a=<true yes yeah 1 0 nope no false>;my%h=@a Z=> reverse @a;S:ii/(@a)/{%h{lc $0}}/}

for @tests -> ($a,$b) {
  is answer-flip($a), $b, "$a => $b";
  is answer-flip($b), $a, "$b => $a";
}
```

Which prints out `1..26` on a line, followed by 26 lines of `ok ...` messages.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, <strike>332</strike> <strike>274</strike> 205 bytes

```java
String s(String p){String[]l={"True","true","Yes","yes","Yeah","yeah","0","1","nope","Nope","no","No","false","False"};for(int j=0;j<14;j++)if(p.matches(l[j]+".?"))return p.replace(l[j],l[13-j]);return"";}
```

Gotta love the uncreative Java golf! Credit to @Leaky Nun for helping!

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<14;j++)if(p.matches(l[j]))return p.replace(l[j],l[14-j]);` (I'll let you figures out which `14` strings to keep :p )

Answer (score 0):

Python 154 bytes

```
a=['True','True.','true','Yes','Yes.','yes','Yeah','Yeah.','yeah','0','False','False.','false','No','No.','no','Nope','Nope.','nope',1]
a[a.index(i)+10]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Emacs Lisp 221 Bytes

```
(defun g(a b)(when(string-match a s)(throw s(replace-match b'()'()s))))
(defun f(s)(catch s(dolist(l'(("true"."false")("yeah"."nope")("yes"."no")("0"."1")))(let((a(car l))(d(cdr l))(case-fold-search t))(g a d)(g d a)))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(defun g (a b)
  ;; when a is in s (dynamical scope) throws the replacement string
  (when (string-match a s)
    (throw s (replace-match b nil nil s))))

(defun f (s)
  (catch s ; catch replacement
    (dolist (l'(("true"."false")("yeah"."nope")("yes"."no")("0"."1")))
      (let ((a(car l))
            (d(cdr l))
            ;; Emacs string-match ignores case, when case-fold-search is true.
            ;; The standard is t, but through customization/local variables
            ;; this can change. Therefore we set it explicitly.
            ;; We could have saved 20 bytes here...
            (case-fold-search t))
        (g a d)
        (g d a)))))
```

The main "feature" here, is that `string-match` can be made to ignore case and that `replace-match` is somewhat intelligent with replacing. For instance, this would also work with TRUE and FALSE. We also exploit dynamical scope to save typing.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 113 bytes

```powershell
$x=($s=(echo True False Yes No 0 1 Yeah Nope)|%{$_;$_|% *wer}|%{$_;"$_."}).indexOf("$args")
$s[$x+4-8*($x%8-ge4)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFBa4MwFMfv@RQPec6k09BCD2VD2C47dpddxhgi9lkHos5Y5lA/u4upXU1zevnl9/6PJFX5Q7XKKM9HTCGEbsQ25KhCTklWwlt9IniJc0XwTgr2Jaxho8s403VFonc7jB4x6l1Y6aDhvHcwks4g5FdxoPY15Q7G9VE5gqH6wPZ@G@xWHFt3FxxpKz7HgbEnzkAvn3vTRM/3zExPLKm8YHnlzdlObbuZ7fTG1lfQdF9aRBq0sH6NVZQWkQZdrbW/WYTEmQmpaNljYGHByZSzKm1XzvKEmYAeXOjMOTYUJxnVz4XSL@wDUltR0tBB/xZGZ6UmdcobDe70J9oNRnCQz06Q0Pd/gni4tDpsGP8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 121 bytes

```python
def f(i):a=[(w,w.title())[i<'a']+'.'[i[-1]>'.':]for w in'true yes yeah 1 false no nope 0'.split()];return a[a.index(i)-4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVBLa8QgEL73V8xNpVnZ0J7Sx7HHnnop4kHYkQhBxcyS5tenvrKg32uG8RF3moN/OY4bWrDcicl8KL4NmyRHC3IhlHtnhulnJply6jLqz6wmbUOCDZxnlO4IO655mxlGsGZZEXzIKyJcmVzj4ogL/ZaQ7smDUUY6f8O/fNrlVR9l0uI85mGgnthPnseGxrII6gGdwS@unardm927HSv0RjO3UuPi5RlU8VUu@xA1smdkH9F3aFiNDw2ruVboTRFbpXHx8gyK0BPE5Dzx8tghf3ZhIY5/)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 32 bytes

```
l'.¡“0žä€¸€¸pe¥æ…Ü‰¦ 1“#Â‡'.ýs.Ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpKBrp6BkX1n5P0dd79DCRw1zDI7uO7zkUdOaQzvAREHqoaWHlz1qWHZ4zqOGDYeWKRgC1SgfbnrUsFBd7/DeYr3D/f91/ocUlaZyuSXmFKdygZh6ELYeVwlIPA0sXgIWT4OIR6YWc/nlgyg9IK3HVQnk5@WDKD0grcdlwGUIlEzMAEoWpAKFgaw8EAskpgcW1AOL6oGF9QA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 103 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(a=/%|Y|y|T|t|rue|0|ope|o|es|eah|1|alse|f|F|n|N|%/g,x=>G[17-G.indexOf(x)],G=(a+0).split`|`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBNj8IgEIbv@yt6MUK2YnvaUz3am3vxYoyJpA7aDWFIQUOT@e9dgdbL@/HMQAh/8iVdN/TWbwzeYFLNFJpdEANYLTtgstmu6EQjHcnT8ASqCC0QEjgC@aCapHZAivZk6ECr7b18n2/P9c@mFb25QfhVLPBL2TZMfldcOKt7f6UrnxQOLBSoivPX@vi@el1mFzH4GfgFnMDNluqY6zjXOsm8KB95lD12sYAU9vHJn5CQWpD6oANmTcVg1lSqJPOShTzJHrtYQAwXXnRoHGoQGu8slEX8Dj79Aw)